# How to select all languages when creating a package?

Tags: sxa, packages

Are all languages of specific item selected by default, when creating a **package** (not by default, but if the item exist for that language then it is selected automatically) if I do not have a `language filter` on? Or I should select all languages manually where the item exist? (English, German, Italian...)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, all language versions of an item will be packaged if you use the `Items statically` option in the `Package Designer`, likewise all language versions will be added if you use the `Items dynamically` option, and then select do not check any language options within the `Language filter`.

If an item does not have a version in a particular language, then one will not be packaged.

[image]

Hope this helps!